# GCP App Engine: Migrate services from the flexible environment to the standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There is [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/migrating) on migrating GCP App Engine services from standard to flexible, though none on going the other direction. It seems flexible is more stringent, and so less work is required going from flex to standard, but I'm not certain, as a simple change in the app.yaml is breaking the app.

Any insight out there on smoothly changing from GCP App Engine flex env to standard?

thank you-

Comment: Technically, Standard is more stringent than Flex because Standard is run within a sandbox env & so they restrict what you can do. Best thing is for you to detail the specific issues you're facing with your switch or the error you're receiving because of the switch

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the time, code written for Flex will work on Standard (unchanged).  What you do need to do is make sure to make all the necessary changes in your app.yaml (it's not as simple as just removing `env: flex`).

One option to do this is pull up the [Flex app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=python) side-by-side with the [Standard app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python) and make sure you:

1. Use valid settings for Standard (e.g. `runtime: python39` instead of using the `runtime_config` field)
2. Remove any settings that are not applicable for Standard (e.g., Healthchecks)

In particular, pay attention to the Scaling settings, as they are similar, but have some easily-missed differences (e.g. `min_num_instances` for Flex, `min_instances` for Standard).

Also, if you are using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard), there are some differences in how you configure the connection.

Comment: Appreciate the answer; prior to posting the question and after taking your answer into account, the app w/ its yaml file deploys successfully, everything in the dashboard seems to be in order, yet when my react app makes a request, the request fails, and still not sure why